# How to find the middle of a line in a file

Tags: python-3.x, caesar-cipher

I am writing a code for class and having some trouble finding the middle of a line. I have to prompt the user for a file, read it, split it into individual lines, and then add a specific word to the beginning, middle, and end of each line. I am not sure how to get the middle

```
file = str(input("Enter input file:" ""))
my_file = open(file, "r")
file_contents = my_file.read()
#change all "e"s to "zw"s 
        for letter in file_contents:
            if letter == "e":
                file_contents = file_contents.replace(letter, "zw")
#add "hokie" to beginning, middle, and end of each line
        lines = file_contents.split('\n')
#I know the following line is wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it
        middle_message = lines[len(lines) /2:] + "hokie"
        message = "hokie" + middle_message + "hokie"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have a better time solving most of this by yourself.

Here's a hint though: what should `middle_message` contain?
For a concrete example, if the line were `'ABCD'`, we want to change the line to `'hokieABhokieCDhokie'`.
See if you can point out where the `AB` and `CD` parts come from in your code snippet.